# How to stop the swatchdog scipt running in the background?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon

Under Ubuntu 20 I have installed [Swatchdog](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/swatchdog.1p.html) and started five daemon processes (running in the background).

Now I wanted to stop the script, so I used `apt-get remove swatch`.

However, as I could notice, this did not remove the background processes.

What is the command to remove the swatchdog processes?

I used `ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?` to list all background processes and found it with:

```
158434 /usr/bin/swatch
```

I also found `461 watchdogd` but guess it's unrelated.

PS: I guess a server restart would work. But I like to do it without restart.

Answer (score 2):

As [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/swatchdog.1p.html) says:

> Swatchdog will terminate gracefully when it receives a QUIT, TERM, or INT signal.

So you can send those signals to stop the process, in your case
`kill -2 158434` where 158434 is the process PID, or more human variant `kill -INT 158434`

For more detail information see `man kill`.

Hope it helps.